# how to record call in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, call

I want to create an call recorder application in blackberry. While searching in this forum i have got [call-recorder-in-blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044062/call-recorder-in-blackberry) this link. The code given in the below link is fairly understood.

It might be a silly question to you experts but my question is how to us that piece of code. I mean the MyScreen object will work on UIApplication. But how can i make my module start while starting the device, and run in background waiting for the phone call listener to invoke.

---

I have used this below code, it records the call but only if the call is on loud speaker mode. Now how can i do the same without putting in loud speaker mode.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.RecordControl;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.PhoneCall;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.PhoneListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class CatchCall extends Application implements PhoneListener {

    Player player;
    RecordControl recorder;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream output;
    byte[] data;
    boolean yes = false;
    int st;

    public CatchCall() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CatchCall().enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public void callAdded(int callId) {
    }

    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConnected(int callId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method s
        PhoneCall phoneCall = Phone.getCall(callId);
        if (phoneCall != null) {
            if (yes)
                initPlay();
        }
    }

    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (yes) {
            try {
                recorder.commit();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            player.close();
            data = output.toByteArray();
            saveRecordedFile(data);
        }
    }

    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
    }

    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {
    }

    public void callHeld(int callId) {
    }

    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
        Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Are u sure to record this call");
    }

    public void callInitiated(int callid) {

        PhoneCall phoneCall = Phone.getCall(callid);
        if (phoneCall != null) {
            st = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Are u sure to record this call");
            if (st == Dialog.YES)
                yes = true;
            else
                yes = false;
        }

    }

    public void callRemoved(int callId) {
    }

    public void callResumed(int callId) {
    }

    public void callWaiting(int callid) {
    }

    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {
    }

    private void initPlay() {
        try {
            player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio");
            player.realize();
            recorder = (RecordControl) player.getControl("RecordControl");
            output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            recorder.setRecordStream(output);
            recorder.startRecord();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Dialog.alert(e + "");
        }

    }

    public static boolean saveRecordedFile(byte[] data) {
        try {
            String filePath1 = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.music");
            String fileName = "Call Recorder(";
            boolean existed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                try {
                    FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath1 + fileName + i + ").amr");
                    if (!fc.exists()) {
                        existed = false;
                    }
                    fc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Dialog.alert("unable to save");
                    return existed;
                }
                if (!existed) {
                    fileName += i + ").amr";
                    filePath1 += fileName;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(filePath1);
            System.out.println("");
            FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) javax.microedition.io.Connector .open(filePath1, javax.microedition.io.Connector.READ_WRITE);
            if (fconn.exists())
                fconn.delete();
            fconn.create();

            OutputStream outputStream = fconn.openOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(data);
            outputStream.close();
            fconn.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually direct call recording not possible with blackberry. AFAIK that posted code is call recording when call on speakerphone. That means If mobile have the loud speaker, then put a call to loud speaker and record that voice. And look at this discussion, [Call recorder in Blackberry.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044062/call-recorder-in-blackberry)

Comment: i appreciate. your comment on this but my question was little different context from the answer you have gave.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to record the audio of a phone call (other than with a loud speakerphone) as you are trying to do. This is intentional. You would need another approach off the device to do this. However, I can answer your other questions:

To make your application autostart, you can follow these steps: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Configure-an-application-to-start-automatically-when-the/ta-p/444748

Also, as this application above doesn't extend from UiApplication, you should check the "run as a system module" box as well, when you follow the directions above. That way it won't appear on the ribbon or as an icon in the list of applications.

Comment: what is that  You another approach off the device  which will help me?