# How to record a phone call programmatically?

Tags: blackberry

I want to record the phone call programmatically.
I have get the help from [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044062/call-recorder-in-blackberry)
but this code will save the multiple audio files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to record call in blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174914/how-to-record-call-in-blackberry)

Comment: I know this Please see the link in my question.....

Comment: If your question is about how to record a longer segment into a single file, that is what you should ask.

Comment: I am recording call.
It will successfully completed but it saves more than 1 file in the device as recorded call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot record phone calls in blackberry. There is no api to do this. You can probably record if the call is put into loudspeaker as its given in the link provided by you.